# How to find out the feature names selected by RFECV?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

How can I know which particular features are selected with `RFECV`? If I do `X_rfecv_train=selector.transform(X_train)`, I get a numpy array, but I don't know feature names...

```
rf_rec = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, max_depth = 20, max_features = 0.9, 
                                min_samples_leaf = 2, min_samples_split = 0.1, 
                                n_estimators = 100, oob_score=True, class_weight="balanced", 
                                random_state=0)
selector = RFECV(rf_rec, step=1, cv=5)
selector = selector.fit(X_train, y_train)

X_rfecv_train=selector.transform(X_train)
X_rfecv_test=selector.transform(X_test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`get_support()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.get_support). All selectors in scikit-learn should have this method.

```
print(selector.get_support(indices=True))
```

This will print the index of your original features which are selected and present in `X_rfecv_train` and `X_rfecv_test`.